What evidence do we have of an affair between Cardinal Mazarin and Queen Anne?
In pop culture it's like common truth that Cardinal Mazarin and Queen Anne had a love affair. But surprisingly the sources that I consider as most reputable do not say anything about it. For example, their wiki pages.
My initial opinion was very likely "they did" but the evidence is only circumstantial. But now I mostly see evidence of the contrary - circumstantial, again.
Have historical documents survived? Any letters, memoirs, etc?
It was time of Fronde, Mazarin was very unpopular and many pamphlets ("Mazarinades") have circulated against him. I think it's the reason the affair became a common knowledge.
Answers to this quora question can be summarised as "no positive evidence", but without citation of sources. Platonic affection - likely, but that is.
Some sites quote Elizabeth Charlotte, Madame Palatine about even "secret marriage" of Anne and Mazarin. But the problem is Elizabeth Charlotte was born in 1652, she couldn't be a witness herself because of her age. And the sites are of disputable reliability, like this...
EDIT:
Ok, about memoirs - I found Memoirs of Madame de Motteville, who was the queen's maid in that time. I think it's as close as we can get. Here is an excerpt:

After the Duc d'Orleans returned to Court he came
daily to see her. The Prince de Conde and the Due
d'Enghien also came occasionally. But as, at the beginning
of the regency, they were not yet in the little secret council, as they were later, they retired early. The Duc d'Orleans stayed late, and Cardinal Mazarin never missed this fine evening hour, during which the conversation went on
publicly between the queen, the princes, and the minister. At this period, therefore, the Court was a very large one. After this the queen retired to her private rooms. The Duc
d'Orleans then had a private interview and returned to the Luxembourg, leaving Cardinal Mazarin alone with the
queen. The minister stayed sometimes an hour, sometimes
more. The doors of the rooms remained open after the
departure of the Duc d'Orleans, and the Court people, assembled in the little chamber of the Palais-Royal adjoining
the cabinet, remained there talking until the "little council"
was over. When it ended the queen, shortly after, bade
good-night to all who composed what is called the great world. The crowd of great seigneurs and courtiers remained
in the grand cabinet, and it was there that took place, no
doubt, all that gallantry and passionate intrigues can produce. A few men, with four or five persons of our sex, had
the honour of remaining with the queen at all hours when
she was in private. When she had bid good-night, and Cardinal Mazarin had left her, she entered her oratory and remained a full hour
in prayer; after which she came out to supper at eleven
o'clock. Her supper finished, we ate the rest of it, without
order or ceremony

Bold is mine, and if I understand correctly "doors remained open" it means no sexual raltionship.
Victor Cousin (19th century) in his Secret History of the French Court under Richelieu and Mazarin references a lot from Madame de Motteville (above), as well as from  Carnet's Autographes de Mazarin (I could not find English translation of it). Also he cites La Rochefoucauld "Memories", but I couldn't find how close La Rochefoucauld was to the events, maybe he retold gossips. According to this excerpt from Victor Cousin -  Mazarin was very gallant (in words only) to many women, including Madame de Chevreuse, his future enemy:

Mazarin knew how to make sacrifices enough to avoid making too many of them, treating everybody with circumspection, suffering no one to despair, promising a great deal, performing as little as possible, and lavishing homage and attentions upon Madame de Chevreuse herself, without ever deceiving himself as to her real sentiments. She, on her part, paid him back in the same coin. La Rochefoucauld says, that at this early period Madame de Chevreuse and Mazarin coquetted with each other. Madame de Chevreuse, who had always mingled coquetry with politics, seems to have essayed the power of her charms on the cardinal. The latter did not fail to lavish gallant words on her, and "even sometimes endeavored to make her believe that she inspired him with love." These are the precise words of La Rochefoucauld. There were some other women, too, who would not have been sorry to have won a little admiration from the prime minister. Among these was the Princess de Guymené, one of the most celebrated beauties of the French court, and not of a savage humor. She and her husband were friendly to Mazarin, despite all the efforts of Madame de Montbazon and Madame de Chevreuse, her mother and sister-in-law. It was evident, indeed, that Mazarin was very attentive to Madame de Guymené, and that he did not scruple to offer her, as well as Madame de Chevreuse, a thousand compliments; but he went no further, and the two beautiful women knew not what to think of so many flatteries and so much reserve. They sometimes jestingly asked each other which of the two he wanted; and as he made no advances, though all the while continuing his gallant protestations, "these ladies," says Mazarin, "conclude thence that I am impotent."

Yes, getting deeper in history you often find it's not black-and-white, "stranger than fiction".
If anybody can provide sources I missed or have no access - I will be very grateful.

Welcome to HSE. Please consider revising your question to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research. That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our help center, and other stacks provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

This article systematically analyzes the accusations in the pamphlets in graphic detail: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/286688.pdf. Based on a quick skim, I see zero reason to think these accusations had any basis in anything factual about their relationship. But it's impossible to prove some plausible private act never actually did take place, so, I expect this question will be unanswerable.

@Brian Z - unfortunally this article is paywalled for me

@Heopps That's what SciHub, Anna's Archive, etc. etc. are for ;)
